# Swift - Store Dates of Step Counter in Firebase Database

Tags: swift, database, firebase, core-motion

I've created a pedometer that stores in a firebase database. However it only stores step data for that one day and when I start another day the steps disappear. I'm guessing I would need to store this data under separate dates to see how many steps were taken each day. I cannot work out how to implement this into my own code. Any help in how to add the date to separate child nodes would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion
import Dispatch
import Firebase

class PedometerViewController: UIViewController {

// Declarations of Pedometer
private let activityManager = CMMotionActivityManager()
private let pedometer = CMPedometer()
private var shouldStartUpdating: Bool = false
private var startDate: Date? = nil
var stepNumberVule: Int = 0

// Storyboard connections
@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var stepsCountLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var activityTypeLabel: UILabel!

private func updateStepCounterValue(_ numberOfSteps: NSNumber) {
    stepNumberVule = numberOfSteps.intValue
    stepsCountLabel.text = numberOfSteps.stringValue
}

func getPedValue() {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    ref.child("user").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
let ped:Int = value?["pedometer"] as? Int ?? 0
 self.stepNumberVule = ped
 self.stepsCountLabel.text = ("\(self.stepNumberVule)")
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    }

@IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let key = ref.child("user").child(user)
    ref.child("user/\(user)/pedometer").setValue(self.stepNumberVule)

}

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    startButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapStartButton), for: .touchUpInside)
  }
// Do additional tasks associated with presenting the view
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    guard let startDate = startDate else { return }
    updateStepsCountLabelUsing(startDate: startDate)
 }
@IBAction func Ready(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.startButton.isHidden = true
}

// Ready? button tapped
@objc private func didTapStartButton() {
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Tab Bar", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUp") as! PopUpViewController
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    shouldStartUpdating = !shouldStartUpdating
    shouldStartUpdating ? (onStart()) : (onStop())
}
 }

// Pedometer Extension and its private fuctions (functions are explained explicitly so no need for comments)
 extension PedometerViewController {
private func onStart() {
    startButton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
    startDate = Date()
    checkAuthorizationStatus()
    startUpdating()
 }

private func onStop() {
    startButton.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
    startDate = nil
    stopUpdating()
 }

private func startUpdating() {
    if CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() {
        startTrackingActivityType()
    } else {
        activityTypeLabel.text = "Not available"
 }

    if CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable() {
        startCountingSteps()
    } else {
        stepsCountLabel.text = "Not available"
    }
 }

private func checkAuthorizationStatus() {
    switch CMMotionActivityManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case CMAuthorizationStatus.denied:
        onStop()
        activityTypeLabel.text = "Not available"
        stepsCountLabel.text = "Not available"
    default:break
    }
 }

private func stopUpdating() {
    activityManager.stopActivityUpdates()
    pedometer.stopUpdates()
    pedometer.stopEventUpdates()
 }

private func on(error: Error) {
    //handle error
 }

// Update step count
private func updateStepsCountLabelUsing(startDate: Date) {
    pedometer.queryPedometerData(from: startDate, to: Date()) {
        [weak self] pedometerData, error in
        if let error = error {
            self?.on(error: error)
        } else if let pedometerData = pedometerData {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.updateStepCounterValue(pedometerData.numberOfSteps)
            }
        }
    }
 }
// Activity type
private func startTrackingActivityType() {
    activityManager.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) {
        [weak self] (activity: CMMotionActivity?) in
        guard let activity = activity else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if activity.walking {
                self?.activityTypeLabel.text = "You're walking"
            } else if activity.stationary {
                self?.activityTypeLabel.text = "You're still"
            } else if activity.running {
                self?.activityTypeLabel.text = "You're running"
            } else if activity.automotive {
                self?.activityTypeLabel.text = "Driving"
            }
        }
    }
}
// Start counting steps
private func startCountingSteps() {
    pedometer.startUpdates(from: Date()) {
        [weak self] pedometerData, error in
        guard let pedometerData = pedometerData, error == nil else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self?.updateStepCounterValue(pedometerData.numberOfSteps)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also show your datastructure? And it would be nice if you could indent the code in you question a bit better (using spaces and not tabs)

Comment: I've added the firebase data structure, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help get you going the right direction, if not, let me know and I will edit.

Here's the 10k foot level concept.

Your step data needs to be stored in separate nodes so a sample Firebase structure would look like this

```
users
   uid_0
      name: "Connor"
      steps:
        -asjs89u8d094f
           date: 20180320
           pedometer: 74
        -u999d9ks90dfk
           date: 20180321
           pedometer: 82
```

an instead of this

> ref.child("user/(user)/pedometer").setValue(self.stepNumberVule)

it would be something like this

```
let thisUsersStepsRef = your_firebase.child("users").child(uid).child("steps")
let refToAdd = thisUsersStepsRef.childByAutoId()
refToAdd.setValue(["date": "20180320", "pedometer", "74")
```

which will write a structure like this within the uid_0 node.

```
 steps:
    -asjs89u8d094f
       date: 20180320
       pedometer: 74
```

the -asjd...and -u999... keys are created with childByAutoId and I just used those strings as placeholders.

Storing it in this fashion allows each days steps to recorded separately. It's generally often a good idea to disassociate node names (keys) from the child data it contains; it's make changing things a lot easier long term and make it much more manageable and expandable.